# Can't force <td> element to obey certain size constraints

Tags: html, css, size, html-table

I have a table :

- The first row and column (expect the origin (0;0) cell) contain buttons;
- The last row and column (expect their first respective cells) are empty;
- All other cells in the middle (i.e not adjacent to a table border) are keys;
- The table size dynamically changes using JavaScript.
- All key cells (in the middle) have a size that depends on their number, and col/row-span. For example, with 4 horizontal keys, if the second key has a colspan of 2, the sizes are 25%, 50%, 25%, and the third key doesn't exist.

You will see better with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znLUt/embedded/result/)

I would like the `<td>` elements containing buttons to respect the following constraints :

- For the horizontal button set (on the first row), a **fixed height** of say 20 pixels;
- for the vertical button set (on the first column), a **fixed width** of the same size as above (that would result in a square (0;0) cell);
- The last button of the first row (class="AddCol") must have the **same width** as the other buttons in that row (it is not the case, and i don't understand why this is not automatic...);
- The last button of the first column (class="AddRow") must have the **same height** as the other buttons in that column (same).

Do you know how I could do that ? I tried to add hidden content to fill "empty" cells", I tried to force the size of different elements, etc... but I'm out of ideas right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `table-layout: fixed;` while setting the size on the `<td>` elements.

Comment: Can it really be that simple ? Let's try.

Comment: Mmmm i'm having a hard time getting this to work. Could you be more specific or would you modify myfiddle please ? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrkRH/5/). The problem with the last button on the first column is that it is filling up the rest of the table instead of taking up the space it should have. In order to make it the same size, that row will need content that will make the browser think that it is important enough to give more space to it. Since your table is dynamically sized in your JavaScript, I can't help you further unless I see that. But that should get you most of what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! It works fine expect for the last button of the first column. I added a dummy content as you said as well as visibility: hidden; but ti's height is smaller by a few pixels than the buttons above it. I don't really understand why. Shouldn't it have the same once i added a content ? Is it a problem with borders ?

Comment: Borders are causing the issue. Are you ok with being a couple pixels off? If not, adding the black borders to the `td`s themselves might help.
Setting `visibility: hidden` isn't a great solution. Try to avoid dummy content as much as possible. Maybe the content of the grey buttons could be the row/column number?

Comment: I've added some content to the last buttons, borders to all non button cells, visibility hidden to the empty cells, and it works, thanks.